# How to get rectangle of view in its constructor

Tags: android

I am creating a custom compounding control extending LinearLayout. Inside of its constructor, program needs to figure out the control's rectangle area. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about do this job in onMeasure call.

Comment: Thanks for giving me a right direction. It took a while but I was able to divide my code for the onMeasure call and it works great.